# Aggregate Initialization of struct with dependent fields

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Is it legal to do the following?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    int bar;
    int baz;
};

int main()
{
    Foo instance = { 5, instance.bar };
    std::cout << instance.baz << std::endl;
}
```

I think it's not because as far as I know the order of initialization is unspecified and the `bar` field can be initialized after `baz`.

Am I right?

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea97713515dd0687

Comment: At the time of initialization, `instance` is not created yet so you cannot refer a field in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you liked your conundrum, this is really gonna bake your noodle:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    int bar=0;
    int baz=1;
};

const int cool(const Foo& f) 
{
    std::cout << "Bar: " << f.bar << " Baz: " << f.baz << std::endl;
    return f.bar;
}

int main()
{
    Foo instance = { 5, cool(instance) };
    std::cout << instance.baz << std::endl;
}
```

What a previous poster correctly quoted: [c++ std draft doc](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#6)

> ...all value computations and side effects associated with a given element are sequenced before those of any element that follows it in order.